# subscriber does not listen to my gmail emails

Tags: python, push-notification, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm struggling with the pub/sub api. I have followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). I have created my project, my topic, set up with `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` to be the publisher, and my subscription.

[image]

And finally, that's my code

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError

credentials_path = os.getcwd() + '/credentials.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_path


timeout = 5.0

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = 'MY_SUBSCRIPTION_PATH'


def callback(message):
    print(f'Received message: {message}')
    print(f'data: {message.data}')

    if message.attributes:
        print("Attributes:")
        for key in message.attributes:
            value = message.attributes.get(key)
            print(f"{key}: {value}")

    message.ack()           


streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f'Listening for messages on {subscription_path}')


with subscriber:
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except (TimeoutError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()
        streaming_pull_future.result()
```

Because the GH code of gmail's pub/sub didn't work, I got this one from a guide, thus I had to create a service account. Everything seems to work fine, in fact, if I publish a message on the pub/sub api the subscriber is able to catch it.
[image]

But if I send a message to myself to my gmail, it's not able to see it.

Comment: What response message are you receiving?

Comment: You said you granted publish permissions to the gmail service account (`gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`). You also need to start the watch so gmail starts pushing messages to your topic. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_request Did you do that?